# Walking vs. Running Shoes

Tags: running, shoes, walking

Everyday, I walk at a minimum 4-5 miles (because I don't drive). With this much walking, I feel there is a significant potential to injure my legs if I don't use proper support.

Since my current walking shoes are beyond repair and need to be replaced, I've been shopping around. However, everywhere I go has either limited or no selection for walking shoes.

Should I just settle for a good pair of running shoes, or is the difference between the two (in terms of support) significant enough that I should keep looking for wanking shoes.

Comment: Isn't walking a very slow form of running? As such, running shoes should be okay to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from my own personal experience and research on running and walking I would suggest the following:

If you're only going to walk, traditional running shoes are fine. They promote landing on your heel and push through to your forefoot which is good walking form.

If your are going to run, I suggest getting a minimalist style running shoe. This promotes correct running form which is "forefoot running". These shoes promote landing on your forefoot instead of your heel. Landing on your heel actually detracts from running by stopping your momentum and also causes unnecessary strain on your knees. I had a minor knee injury a couple years ago which I attribute to using traditional running shoes when running.

In fact you could probably just get minimalist shoes for both running and walking since when you walk you naturally tend to go from your heel to your forefoot without the influence of the shoe. However, shoes have a larger influence on running form.

Sources:

http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/news/20120601/barefoot-running-can-be-great-tread-carefully?src=RSS_PUBLIC

http://www.mensfitness.com/leisure/outdoor/the-first-scientific-support-for-minimalist-running

Comment: Do you have any references to back up that one running form is better than another for any given person?

Comment: What do you mean? You want me to back up that landing on the balls of your feet is better then landing on your heels? Clearly people can have have different running forms, but there are some constants that dictate what is good running form and what is bad form. Running on the balls of your feet is considered good for the reasons I stated in my answer. Like I said in my answer, this is based on research that I have done. If the poster does a little research, they would find similar information.

Comment: Here is one source. http://www.mensfitness.com/leisure/outdoor/the-first-scientific-support-for-minimalist-running

Comment: Here is another: http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/news/20120601/barefoot-running-can-be-great-tread-carefully?src=RSS_PUBLIC

Comment: Do be careful if you go for a minimalist shoe.  The transition has to be very gradual.  I have many clients and friends who have been injured.  However, many people swear by them, and if you can get on with them they do encourage you to run more as nature intended. You may find this link useful. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/how-should-i-transition-into-minimalist-running-shoes

Answer (score 0):

If you are going out to buy shoes I would definitely go for walking shoes.  For the following reasons:-
They are more supportive all round.
They will last longer
They will keep your foot drier in a downpour.